# How to connect Acer E330 Glow to Ubuntu 13.04 in MTP mode?

Tags: 13.04, android, acer, mtp

Well the title is quite clear I guess. How can I connect my ACER E330 LIQUID GLOW to Ubuntu 13.04 through the USB-cable? It works just fine PTP-mode(camera) but not in MTP-mode (media). My phone works on android 4.0. I already tried a bunch of stuff but it didn't work...

Thanks